# PyQt4 Gui that prints loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, pyserial

I'm trying to learn PyQt4 and has made the following Gui for this purpose - it has no other use.

The code works almost as expected - the only thing that doesn't is the 'else' clause.

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__ (self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.startButton = QPushButton('Start')
        self.stopButton = QPushButton('Stop')
        self.browser = QTextBrowser()
        self.myLabel = QLabel()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.myLabel)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.startButton.setFocus()
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.guiLoop)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.guiLoop)
        self.setWindowTitle('Loop Gui')


    def guiLoop(self):
        state = False
        text = self.sender()
        self.myLabel.setText(text.text())
        time.sleep(1)
        if text.text() == 'Start':
            state = True
        else:
            state = False
        i = 0
        while state:
            time.sleep(.1)
            self.browser.append(str(i))
            QApplication.processEvents()
            i += 1
        else:
            self.browser.append('Stop loop')
            time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

...I'd expect that the program would print 'Stop loop' in the browser widget before exiting, but it doesn't

```
       else:
            self.browser.append('Stop loop')
            time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit()
```

**I now have 3 questions:**

1. Why doesn't it print 'Stop loop'
2. If you imagine that the loop was instead a data stream from a serial connection, how could I print only every 10th value. In the loop that would be 1, 11, 21 ... and so on
3. General comments on my code

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line in your else part

```
QApplication.processEvents()
```

like

```
while state:
    time.sleep(.1)
    if i % 10 == 1:
        self.browser.append(str(i))
        QApplication.processEvents()
    i += 1
else:
    self.browser.append('Stop loop')
    QApplication.processEvents()
    time.sleep(3)
    sys.exit()
```

Output is like: 1 11 21 31 etc.. and Stop Loop